# Chrome extension talking to GA Script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script

I'd like to build a Chrome extension with a backend interface for an admin. I'm new to Chrome extensions but I'm very comfortable using Google Apps Script to build custom functionality in Google Sheets. Therefore, I'd like to design my backend within a Google Sheet.

My question is, can a Chrome extension and an instance of GAS tied to a Sheet communicate in some way? If so how would I set that up? I've seen that Chrome extensions can access Drive through an API, but that requires OAuth which just gets messy. Ideally, my extension and my GAS could just communicate directly with one another.

Any thoughts on how to go about implementing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you publish a script as a webapp, you can pass parameters in the url. [Check out the documentation for doGet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)

Comment: Thank you for the resource. However, how would I communicate the other way? i.e. have the script talk to the Chrome extension?

Comment: I think if you wanted GAS to communicate with the extension without a request first being made by the extension, you would need some kind of API service that sits in between the two. The other method could be to poll the GAS web app url from your extension at regular intervals for any changes.

Comment: Ah, good idea! The functionality I need isn't time-sensitive, so I think regular polling would work just fine. Do you know if Chrome can read the output at a particular URL without opening a tab visible to the user?

Comment: I'm having trouble with this. Is the best way to create an iframe within background.html and then attempt to read it? I'm not allowed to run inline scripts in the background.html so I can't get this to work...